# Modules do not start in Google App Engine Python on Development Server

Tags: android, google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-endpoints

**Problem:** 
I am trying to create a simple app to try Modules in Google App Engine Python on Development Server(Development SDK 1.9.2).  But I do not see the modules getting started at runtime(log messages specifying the ports on which they are started).

Logs when I start the app using the Launcher on the development server:

```
2014-04-13 02:40:47 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=11080', '--admin_port=8003', u'C:\\gaurav\\coding\\python\\androidbackend1']"
INFO     2014-04-13 02:40:50,572 devappserver2.py:764] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2014-04-13 02:40:50,627 api_server.py:171] Starting API server at: http://localhost:59432
INFO     2014-04-13 02:40:50,631 dispatcher.py:182] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:11080
INFO     2014-04-13 02:40:50,634 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8003
INFO     2014-04-13 02:40:56,062 module.py:627] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12
```

[This Modules doc page at GAE for Python](https://google-developers.appspot.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/) does not mention anything about development server. From another link, I figured out that on development server, all the modules are started at the beginning of app execution and they only differ in the port number of their URLs

**Context:** 
I created a new app using the Google Launcher which generates a default "main.py" and "app.yaml". I then copied the "main.py" into a file named "modulem1.py", while retaining "main.py". I copied "app.yaml" into a file named "modulem1.yaml", while retaining the "app.yaml" file. I added the following line to "modulem1.yaml":

```
module: modulem1
```

I want to use Google Endpoints API to interact between the web app and Android app. So I need to use module for that and therefore I am trying a small web app with modules

I should be missing something obvious. Appreciate any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using the Google App Engine Launcher, then you will need to provide the full path to your second yaml file **modulem1.yaml**

[image: Configuration]

Then once you start it, you can view the Logs and see that the **modulem1** module has been launched at `http://localhost:8080` and the **default** module has been launched at `http://localhost:8081`

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot IanGSY. That solved my problem. It is really nice of you to put the screenshots here.  
I wonder how this very relevant piece of information is missing from the relevant [official Google doc on Modules in Python](https://google-developers.appspot.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/).. I lost 5 hours looking for this information before I posted the question here

Comment: Thank you IanGSY, and for the extra work of adding the screenshots.  Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: One note: If you have other flags, like setting the --host, make sure this flag is added AFTER the others

Comment: Do you know any way to make the *default* module run on port 8080, and other modules on ports 8081 and more?

Comment: This is the `Info...` screen, found by right clicking on the project line and selecting `Info...` from the context menu.